# Dynamically Changing BLE Advertisement Data Android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to change the BLE Advertisement data while BLE advertisement is going on(with out having to stop and start the advertisement).

Use Case : Reading a value of sensor (Say Accelerometer sensor) and advertising it every 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with the [setAdvertisingData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertisingSet.html#setAdvertisingData(android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData)) method from the AdvertisingSet class. However this class was added in API 26 so for previous versions of Android, you will have to restart the advertising.

Comment: And you probably already know this but the best way to handle your use case is to actually establish a connection and deliver all of the value changes via notifications. This is how peripherals in BLE normally work.

Comment: I was trying out  this method as gatt connection was taking a longer time to deliver the information. Gatt connect and disconnect takes more than 4 seconds that is why I tried to do it this way.

Comment: No I am not using the new api 26. i am using 22.