# How do you update the Android BLE Advertiser service data at runtime?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE Advertiser service running with 3 bits of service data running (ex: `010501`) where the `05` could be the version of data that will be set at the characteristic level. I want another device to be able to know to re-read the characteristic without polling it manually. Right now I can restart my advertiser with the new service data when something changes, but there is a ~5-6 second delay for the user. I am wondering if there is a way to update the service data WHILE the advertiser is running. This will lessen the chance of a failure too, as restarting the advertiser can be dicy at times. I need to improve that logic, but for this post, I am wondering if there is a way to avoid the restart completely? Thanks.

Comment: If you are connected to the device you can use notifications to receive a changed value

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question. You want to change the data sent in the advertisement at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [setAdvertisingData](http://setAdvertisingData) method as that should accomplish what you want. Have a look at the links below for more info:-

- [BLE advertisement changing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576564/ble-advertisements-changing-in-android)
- [Dynamically changing BLE advertisement data Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933499/dynamically-changing-ble-advertisement-data-android)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy Advertising](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising)