# android.bluetooth.le changing advertiding data (UUID) periodically

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I made an app that advertises an iBeacon. The UUID changes every 30 seconds. Within the UUID is the androidID of the phone and a timestamp. Both are encrypted. My smarthome system decrypts the UUID and gets the timestamp and the androidID.If both are valid the front door opens.
The app creates an UUID and starts advertising, stops after 30 seconds an creates a new one and restarts the advertising. This goes on for ever until the app (running in backround) doesn't get closed.
I wonder if it is possible to change the advertising data (UUID) without stopping and restarting the  advertising??

Thanks!

Is starting with AdvertisingSet a solution??

Comment: I don't really  get what the AdvertisingSet is for. I couldn't find an example

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is via the **setAdvertisingData()** method. Calling this in the middle of advertising shouldn't be an issue (as long as you are on API 26 or later). From the [Android developer website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertisingSet.html#setAdvertisingData(android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData)):-

> Set/update data being Advertised. Make sure that data doesn't exceed
> the size limit for specified AdvertisingSetParameters. This method
> returns immediately, the operation status is delivered through
> callback.onAdvertisingDataSet().
>
> Advertising data must be empty if non-legacy scannable advertising is
> used. For apps targeting Build.VERSION_CODES#R or lower, this requires
> the Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission which can be gained
> with a simple  manifest tag. For apps targeting
> Build.VERSION_CODES#S or or higher, this requires the
> Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE permission which can be gained
> with Activity.requestPermissions(String[], int). Requires
> Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE

Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [How do you update the Android BLE advertising data at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182874/how-do-you-update-the-android-ble-advertiser-service-data-at-runtime)
- [Dynamically changing BLE data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933499/dynamically-changing-ble-advertisement-data-android)
- [BLE advertisements changing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576564/ble-advertisements-changing-in-android)